# Grails 3 Cookie Plugin - return Null

Tags: grails, cookies

i am trying to use cookie in grails 3.
[i tried this plugin](https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/ctoestreich/cookie) but i don't know why its not work at all..

```
 cookieService.setCookie('username', customer?.email)
```

and i use this code for call it from gsp

```
 <g:cookie name="username"/>
```

i also tried this way..

```
 def cokusername = cookieService.setCookie('username', customer?.email)
                println "cookieService.getCookie('username')  = "+cookieService.getCookie('username')
                redirect(controller: "toko",cokusername: cokusername)
```

and this is in my `tokoController.groovy` index :

```
def index={
        def toko = CifLogo.executeQuery("from CifLogo order by rand()",[max: 10])
//        def itemRandom = Item.executeQuery("from Item where cif = :cif order by rand()",[max:12,cif:cif])
        def awdf = cookieService.getCookie('username')
        println "awdf = "+awdf
        println "cokusername = "+params.cokusername
        [tokoList:toko,cokusername:awdf]
    }
```

i have no idea to retrieve my cookie. :(
[image]

---

update

```
def index(){
        def toko = CifLogo.executeQuery("from CifLogo order by rand()",[max: 10])
//        def itemRandom = Item.executeQuery("from Item where cif = :cif order by rand()",[max:12,cif:cif])
        def awdf = cookieService.getCookie('username')
        println "awdf = "+awdf
        println "cokusername = "+params.cokusername
        [tokoList:toko,cokusername:awdf]
    }
```

[image]

i tried to print `cookie` like this..

```
def awdf = request.getCookie('username')
        println "awdf = "+awdf
        println "cokusername = "+params.cokusername
        request.cookies.each { println "${it.name} == ${it.value}" }
```

and this is what the result

[image]

Comment: I'm using this plugin to store my session on cookies http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/benlucchesi/cookie-session best part is you don't need to deal with cookies code you just have to add stuff into session and it'll be stored in cookie automagically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but maybe it's a bug.

i use this code to setCookie

```
cookieService.setCookie(name:"username", value: customer?.email, maxAge: 24*60*60, path: "/")
```

after read [this code](https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-cookie/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/cookie/CookieService.groovy).

and i cannot deleteCookie with this code.

`cookieService.deleteCookie(cookieService.findCookie("username"))`

because when i print `cookieService.findCookie("username")` it returns `javax.servlet.http.Cookie@78cbf320`

and method `deleteCookie(Cookie cookie)` from [this link](https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-cookie/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/cookie/CookieService.groovy)

so i think it mustbe deleted.

but still availlable.

so i can answer this question about **setCookie** not **deleteCookie**

i also tried this way to delete cookie..but still failed.

```
CookieService.setCookie(name:"username", value: "", maxAge: 0, path: "/")
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see this line:

```
  redirect(controller: "toko",cokusername: cokusername)
```

Should be:

```
  redirect(controller: "toko",params:[cokusername: cokusername])
```

Also actions using closures in grails 3 will have undesired results. You should change to methods. Hence this line:

```
  def index={
```

SHould be:

```
  def index(){
```

Apart from this it seems the `cookieService` code should work fine, so I can only assume its being caused my the closure index that should be a method.

Another thing could be the fact that you are doing a redirect, which will clear the request and not persist any cookies that were set before the redirect

Comment: is there any configuration for cookie path?

Comment: Not sure. But like I said it could definitely be because of the redirect. Try to load a with a tender method and print cookie in a gap to verify it's still there instead of the redirect method